# How To Insert Sheet Name inside An Inserted Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a Column and give it name as "Ref" and eventually insert the value of the name of the sheet. Here it is what I have done:

```
Sub InsertColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ws
        Columns(1).Insert
        Range("1").Value = ActiveSheet.Name
    End With
End Sub
```

As you can see I still have a problem on naming the Column and also do not know how to insert value only until there is row with data on the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert sheet name as long as there is something in column B (after insertion) you could do it in this way:

```
Columns(1).Insert
Dim loRow as Long
    loRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(XlUp).Row
Range("A1", Cells(loRow, "A")).Value = ActiveSHeet.Name
```

You could change `"B" column reference` into different column when needed.

**EDIT after comment**

Your question was/is a bit unclear. This is possibly what you need:

```
Columns(1).Insert
Dim loRow as Long
    loRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(XlUp).Row
RRange("A1", Cells(loRow, "A")).Name = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Kaz buy how about Naming the Column how can I do thta?